# cannot change conda environment in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, conda, anaconda3

[image]

As displayed here, when I activate the conda environment, the environment name does change. However, it is not using the environment. the python path is still /usr/bin/python.

Can someone help me out with this. Thanks a lot in advance

[image]

Added the conda env list

Comment: @medium-dimensional Hi, I have added the conda env list to the post

Comment: @medium-dimensional I tried all the answers, but sadly still the same

Comment: the outputs are all the same, the environment name changes, but the path of python is still /usr/bin/python. Even I tried source activate or change the settings in vscode

Comment: You need to set the interpreter with specific conda env.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments
https://medium.com/@udiyosovzon/how-to-activate-conda-environment-in-vs-code-ce599497f20d

Comment: @AkhilJain if you mean, cmd+shift+p, and then select interpreter, I tried but sill not working